# how to configure to getting general query logs and slow query logs in mysql

Tags: mysql, linux

OS is ubuntu 16.04

MySQL version: `MySQL  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

In my system

`/etc/mysql/ -> ls`

`conf.d`  debian.cnf  debian-start  my.cnf  my.cnf.fallback  mysql.cnf  `mysql.conf.d`

in which file I need to config for getting general query logs and slow query logs.

Answer (score 0):

TO setup Query Log put below line in your /etc/my.cnf under [mysqlId] section.

```
general_log_file = /path/to/query.log
general_log      = 1
```

To enable from MySql Console:

```
SET general_log = 1;
```

Reference: See [query log doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html)

Alternatively turn on log:

```
SET global general_log = 1;
```

Caution, general_log on a busy system generates many bytes per second.
Before very long, you need to:

```
SET global general_log = 0;
```

to avoid filling your storage device.  End of Caution.

Now enable slow query log:
Log in to mysql console: `mysql -u root -p`

Enable slow query log: mysql> `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON'`

When slow query log is enable it logs query which taking more then 10s. TO change this value: `SET GLOBAL long_query_time = X;`

Change slow query log file location: `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log_file = '/path/filename';`

Restart the mysql service: `sudo service mysqld restart`

If you want to turn off slow query log: `SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Abhijit said, have this:

```
log_output = FILE
```

(Other possibilities are `TABLE` and `FILE,TABLE`.)